# Is there a way to know which levels lead to secret areas/have switches in them?

Tags: kirbys-adventure

I found my first level with a switch in it (Level 3-1), and it was pretty easy to see (I just had to figure out how to get to it).

However, I suspect that this might not always be the case.

Is there a way to know, ahead of starting a level, if it has a secret switch in it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a stage, there isn't any warning about whether a hidden switch is present. However, you can take some guesses based on the door you're going into, and what amount of the level is blocked off.

However, if you *miss* a secret switch, then the star that normally appears on a cleared door is not shown (or is it darkened out? Something like that). This is how you can tell you *missed* a switch. Going back and finding the switch will cause the star to be present when you clear the level.